# proof verification of if $x$ is the limit superior then there is only finite amount of $n$ st $x+\epsilon<x_n$ and infinite of $x-\epsilon<x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

this definition is from introduction to real analysis by Robert G.Bartle forth edition section 3.4 page 83 definition 3.4.10 and theorem 3. 4.11 the author include proof of these theorem but I did understand it so I tried to prove it
but he didn't even define a decreasing sequence

> Definition :The limit superior of $x_n$ is the infimum of the set $V$ of $v \in \mathbb{R}$   such that $v < x_n$ for at
> most a finite number of $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

with this detention I want to prove that
If $\epsilon > 0$:
 $1)$ there are at most a finite number of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x+\epsilon<x_n$, 
$2)$ but an infinite number of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x-\epsilon<x_n$

**my proof is**

Case $1)$
if $v<x_n$ for at most finite amount of time then there is a number $m \in \mathbb{N}$ st $\forall n>m$ $v≥x_n$ then as $x=\inf{V}$ then $x≤v<x+\epsilon$ $\forall n>m$
and because $v≥x_n$ $\forall n>m$ then $x+\epsilon >x_n$ $\forall n>m$
then at most there is $m$ number of $x+\epsilon <x_n$

Case $2)$
as there is infinite number of $n>m$ st $v≥x_n$ then
$v-\epsilon<x_n≤v$ and we know that $x≤v$ then $x-\epsilon≤v-x$ for infinite many $n$
then it follow that $x-\epsilon<x_n$

I am pretty sure that the first case proof is right but the second is not because it implies that for all n >m this assertion always hold which I don't think is true , but I had no other idea how to prove it

Comment: Where is this definition from?

Comment: @bb_823
introduction to real analysis by Robert G.Bartle forth edition section 3.4 page 83 definition 3.4.10 and theorem 3. 4.11
the author include proof of these theorem but I did understand it so I tried to prove it

Comment: @bb_823 I think it would be better to define it as $lim_{n \to \infty} \sup(x_n)$

Comment: For part 2) Since $x-\epsilon <x$ it follows that $x-\epsilon\notin V$ and hence by definition of $V$, $x-\epsilon <x_n$ for infinitely many $n$. Your part 1) is fine.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I didn't understand that how does this prove the case2 and is there any other proof?

Comment: Let me rephrase. If any number $v\notin V$ then we have $v<x_n$ for infinitely many $n$ because $V $ contains only those numbers which are exceeded by at most a finite number of $x_n$. This is all a part of definition of $V$.

Comment: The question [there are only finitely many n with $v+ϵ<x_n$ and $2)$ there are infinitely many $n$ with $v−ϵ<x_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/979840/152299) seems similar to this one.

Comment: @CiaPan it is the same question but the answer use another definition , I want a proof without the decreasing sequence

Comment: @ParamanandSingh can you please write a detailed answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first proof is correct but, in my opinion, you can come up with something simpler if you observe that the set $ V $ has the property: if $ a \notin V $ then for all $ b < a $ we have $ b \notin V $.

For the second proof I don't think your claim $ v−\epsilon <x_n \le v $ holds for $ v \in V $. The proof can be made really simple by observing that if the second claim does not hold, then $ x - \epsilon \in V $. This is an obvious contradiction with $x$ being the infimum of $ V $.